# Array is overwriting previous object

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml

I am creating an object with my XML data and pushing into the array. But when it coming out from the method I can see all the array value is copy of first one. Can anyone help me.

Here is my code :

```
var obj = {};
for(var i = 1; i < myData.length; i++) {

    var myDAtt = myData[i].getElementsByTagName('D');

    for(var j = 0; j < myDAtt.length; j++){
        obj[myDAtt[j].getAttribute('dataIndex')] = myDAtt[j].getAttribute('V')
    }

    me.Rec.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Move `var obj = {}` inside the `for(var i=1; i<myData.length;i++){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new object in the top level `for` loop. In your case you have only one variable, for which you are adding properties and push into the array it's reference. So at the end you have one big object and pushed the reference of it into the array for many times.

```
for(var i = 1; i < myData.length; i++) {

    var obj = {};
    var myDAtt = myData[i].getElementsByTagName('D');

    for(var j = 0; j < myDAtt.length; j++) {
        obj[myDAtt[j].getAttribute('dataIndex')] = myDAtt[j].getAttribute('V')
    }

    me.Rec.push(obj);
}
```